# Headset not connecting with windows 8 bluetooth

Tags: windows-8, bluetooth, headset

I have an LG HBS 730 headset and I am trying to connect it to my laptop (HP Pavilion n031se) via Bluetooth.

The problem is Bluetooth discovers the headset, connects with it, but then shows the device as not connected. Moreover the headset doesn't show the connection being established (via light blink)

[image: Screenshot]

I have tried updating the Bluetooth driver from hp.com, but it doesn't work. Moreover it easily connects to my mobile phone.

Comment: Try right clicking on your speaker icon in the taskbar and select "Playback devices". Find your headphones in the list. (There may be more than one of it. If so, one may be better audio quality than the other). Right click on your headset and select "Set as Default Device". Let me know if this helps.

Comment: My headphones do not appear in that "Playback devices" list

Comment: It would appear that your headset is not detected as an audio device. But the icon in your screenshot shows a headset...
Is it just a microphone? Either way, try the same steps I gave above, but instead of the "Playback devices" list, try the "Recording devices" list.

Comment: It's a headset, I can listen to audio on it using my mobile phone.
It's also not appearing in "Recording devices" list.